# Split test and training data on multi-label data for imbalanced data on each class

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, training-data

I would like to split my data in train and test data.

My data includes 7 classes and each sample may have different labels so it is a multi-label classification.

Also, my data is imbalanced which means the data in one class may have three times more samples than the data in another class.

I wanted to do `StratifiedKFold` however it seems it is not suitable for multi-label classification.

Can you please let me know what I can do in this situation?

I have looked at this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65828/how-to-use-scikit-learns-cross-validation-functions-on-multi-label-classifiers) and [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27212/stratifiedkfold-valueerror-supported-target-types-are-binary-multiclass/27220)

Thanks.

Comment: look at SMOTE: http://rikunert.com/SMOTE_explained